# What are the "serious caveats" with ZMQ_FD?

Tags: c++, c, events, zeromq

[The ZeroMQ FAQ](http://zeromq.org/area:faq#toc5) states in the **Why can't I use standard I/O multiplexing functions such as select() or poll() on ZeroMQ sockets?** question:

> Note that there's a way to retrieve a file descriptor from ZeroMQ socket (ZMQ_FD socket option) that you can poll on from version 2.1 onwards, however, there are some serious caveats when using it. Check the documentation carefully before using this feature.

I've prototyped integrating ZeroMQ socket receiving to Qt's and custom select() based event loops, and on the first glance everything seems to work.

From the documentation I have identified two "caveats" that I handle in my code:

1. **The ability to read from the returned file descriptor does not necessarily indicate that messages are available to be read from the socket**

   This I have solved by checking ZMQ_EVENTS before reading from the socket.
2. **Events are signaled in edge-triggered fashion**

   This one I have solved by always receiving all the messages from the socket when the file descriptor signals.

Are there some caveats that I'm missing?

Comment: If you are only using regular sockets that should be enough. For thread safe sockets (client-server, radio-dish, scatter-gather) that will not work.

Comment: You'll likely get better answers going to the [zmq mailing list](http://zeromq.org/docs:mailing-lists), StackOverflow isn't so great for these types of open ended questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason. I'll post this question there.

Comment: For reference, the mailing list discussion is here: https://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2016-May/thread.html#30349